# Why Inner-join shows wrong data with where cluase?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

Using where clause in inner join but inner join is not selecting what I asked for in query. Here I am to select only 12-jun data whereas innerjoin query selecting previous date data aswell.

[image: My Table]

QUERY IS:

```
SELECT
    p_sale_inv.datetime,
    p_sale_inv.sale_inv,
    p_sale_inv.Jobber,
    p_sale_part.stock_id,
    p_sale_part.quantity,
    p_sale_part.netamount,
    p_purch_stock.Price,
    p_sale_part.sale_inv
FROM
    p_sale_inv
INNER JOIN p_sale_part ON p_sale_inv.sale_inv = p_sale_part.sale_inv
INNER JOIN p_purch_stock ON p_sale_part.stock_id = p_purch_stock.stock_id
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(p_sale_inv.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-07-12' AND '2018-07-12'
```

[image: AND RESULT IS:]

PROBLEM IS:
Why query showing same date? In actual as you can see above table they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is returning the second row of the `p_sale_inv` table, joined to two rows of the `p_sale_part` table. That is why the dates are the same: they are from the same row of the table.

(Note that only one `p_sale_inv` row has a date that matches the WHERE clause. So you wouldn't expect both rows of that table to be returned.)

Edit:
Maybe this will help clear up the misunderstanding. Here is the same query with the INNER JOIN's removed:

```
SELECT
    p_sale_inv.datetime,
    p_sale_inv.sale_inv,
    p_sale_inv.Jobber,
FROM
    p_sale_inv
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(p_sale_inv.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-07-12' AND '2018-07-12'
```

You will see only one row from the table, the one with a 7-12 date. If you remove the 'WHERE' clause, you will see both rows, and both dates. It is the join's to other tables that are confusing you. I think your next step is to learn about how table joins work.

Comment: I tried even this WHERE DATE_FORMAT(p_sale_inv.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')='2018-07-12' but still same result, how to come over it? any solution?

Comment: I also tried to remove " p_sale_inv.datetime " from select but still it generating same result :(

Comment: Again, you are only getting one p_sale_inv row back because only one row has a date on 7-12. The other row is 7-11 so the WHERE clause prevents it from being returned.

Comment: There are two rows in the output because the parent table p_sale_inv is being JOINed to a child table, p_sale_part. There are two "sale parts" for the one invoice dated 7-12.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, Your help clearup my misunderstanding. innerjoin is such useless thing then :(

Comment: Glad I helped! I will add that JOIN is actually _extremely_ useful. But you don't need it to query a single table... An example of when you'd need it is if someone asked you to return all the items from P_SALE_PART appearing on invoices (in table P_SALE_INV) dated 7/12, whose price (in table P_PURCH_STOCK) is greater than $100. That's the kind of thing JOIN is for. You can learn more about it when you actually need it.